# Why was the LES on Apollo white?

Tags: design, launch-escape-system, atlas-rocket-family, redstone

In below images they’re red for Mercury (both on the Redstone and Atlas boosters). But the Apollo ones are white. Why were the Launch Escape Systems of Apollo white?

[image]

[image]

Comment: The red (actually "[International Orange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_orange)") tower would have been for visibility; the real question is why Apollo's was white.

Comment: @RussellBorogove [This question](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/54890/39424) suggests the tower was painted for visibility instead of the stack, but doesn't say why.

Comment: @Cadence the answers to that question are suspect, to say the least.

Comment: I wondered if for Mercury and Gemini, there might be a point in time where the rocket was on the pad without its service tower, but that doesn't seem likely.

Comment: @RussellBorogove, maybe not then, but now, https://michaelstephenwills.com/2019/09/30/launch-complex-14-today/ (scroll down)

Comment: Just by quick look, it seems that the LES for Mercury was taller than the support tower, so makes sense to paint high-vis.  Apollo launches seem to have the support tower taller than the LES.